# How to write a buffered image in Java to outputstream (System.out) so another program can read (via Pipe | )?

Tags: java, java-io, javax.imageio, system.out, system.in

I am trying to build a pipeline-architecture with java (currently working with NetBeans 8.2 , Windows 10 platform 64bits, jdk 8.0). One program is meant to open a jpg image, store it internally as BufferedImage and pass it forward to the next program (Via System.out), which is suppossed to get the bytes from the System.in input stream, convert them back to BufferedImage and apply some filters, so it can pass the image again to the System.out output stream. The commands I'm supposed to execute in the windows shell is:

```
java -jar OpenImage.jar "lenna.jpg" | java -jar ApplyBlur.jar 10 | java -jar SaveImage.jar "result.jpg" ... (and so on)
```

I have already tried the ImageIO.write method to write to the System.out stream and read it back again with ImageIO.read, but the BufferedImage created is always null. I've also tried to convert the image to byte array (as advised here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-convert-Byte-Array-to-Image-in-java), pass it through a ByteArrayOutputStream and finally to the System.out, but the image is still null.

```
// The OpenImage program:
image = ImageIO.read(new File("lenna.jpg"));
            if(image == null) {
                System.err.println("Image is null!");
            }
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", System.out);

// The SaveImage program:
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(System.in);
```

I expect the ImageIO.read(InputStream) method to sucessfuly read from the System.in, but the resulting image is always null.

Comment: If you run only this: java -jar OpenImage.jar "lenna.jpg" . Do you see the output in console?

Comment: yes, I see a lot of nonsense characters that are supposed to be the bytes. Here is the print screen: http://prntscr.com/o9pczn

Comment: So this is ok should not be readable, its byte stream.

Comment: try to redirect the output to a file and open it as image (`ava -jar OpenImage.jar "lenna.jpg" >lenna2.jpg`)

Comment: If you run this java -jar OpenImage.jar "lenna.jpg" | java -jar ApplyBlur.jar 10 , what you get from BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(System.in); ? image is null?

Comment: just tested using `ImageIO` `write` and `read` - working fine for me

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger the file is saved but I can't open it, somehow the Windows Image handler cannot open it, as if it was not recognized as an image (you can see it via the ss: http://prntscr.com/o9pfnt). HPCS, the image is null, I did a try/catch block to verify if the resulting image is null (you ca see it here http://prntscr.com/o9pgds moreover, I printed the number of bytes avaible in the BYteArrayInputStream just to be sure it wasn't empty)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger which Java jdk and netbeans versions are you using?

Comment: OpenJDK 12.0.1 - no netbeans, used VIM / ar esure not writing anything else to output? I also `flush`ed the output, just to be sure

Comment: Just tried with Java 8 - also working. Read image: `BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(args[0]));
 ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", System.out);
 System.out.flush()` and show image: `BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(System.in);
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new ImageIcon(img));`

Comment: Looks like you call System.out.println() in your code also for something else, and this destroy your byte stream. YOu can not use it for anything else only to output the image bytes.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger are you using windows or linux? Just tried now to execute the OpenImage.jar with CMD (I was using powershell) and put the results to a "test.jpg" (using '>') file. It worked. But now, when I use the Pipe to pass the results to the second program, no error is shown but also no results.

Comment: @HPCS I thought it was the problem too, but I don't use System.out.print for anything else

Comment: using windows, `powershell` is probably messing with your outpu/input

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger you are right. It is finally working. Thank you both very much for the help!